# Using a Windows Forms icon in WPF

Tags: wpf, notifyicon

I've got this WPF code which works...

```
Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/media/images/VS.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

I'm using a windows forms notifyIcon control in my WPF app, and I now need to assing the Icon to it. How do I get from my WPF icon to a System.Drawing.Icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following method:

```
// Setup the new NotifyIcon
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
notifyIcon.Text = "Name of Application";
notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("media/images/VS.ico");
notifyIcon.Visible = true;
```

Make sure you add a reference to System.Drawing.

Comment: Brent, I can't see the systray icon after running your code although it builds ok. My icon is in a resource. Maybe that's the problem? ...

    Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/media/images/VS.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Comment: My current code looks like this...

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/media/images/VS.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);    // this works so the URI is working ok
            notifyIcon.Text = "Name of Application";
            notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("/media/images/VS.ico"); 
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;  // nothing shown in systray
        }

Comment: Possibly... The icon I use has a build action of Content, and I copy the icon to the Output directory.  I'll update my answer...

Comment: Got it now, thanks to your latest tweaks BUT the path to use is "media\images\VS.ico" without the leading slash. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.INTEROP.IMAGING.CREATEBITMAPSOURCEFROMHBITMAP%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

I use it like:

```
return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(source.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

where source is a `Bitmap`, which you can get by calling your `Icon`'s `.ToBitmap()` method.

Comment: I can't see the ToBitmap method anywhere. What class is it a member of? Thanks.

Comment: You accepted the other answer, but for completeness, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap%28v=VS.100%29.aspx . Maybe I'm just confused between the WinForms/WPF Icon classes.